# Show/Hide divs on form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, show-hide

I have worked out about 90% of this, but can't seem to get the last 10%:

I have a form that asks the user to select a location. On select, I want the page (and the request form) to fade in opacity, and a new div to fade up on top with pricing information.

Right now, everything works as expected for the first selected option (novato), but on any other option in the list, the page and request form divs both fade out, and the new pricing div isn't visible.

I'm stumped, and pretty sure I'm just missing something stupid (being a newbie). Any help is appreciated!

the request form:

```
<form id="locations">
<select>
<option>Choose a location</option>
<option></option>
<option id="novato" value="novato">Novato</option>
<option id="sanleandro" value="sanleandro">San Leandro</option>
<option id="livermore" value="livermore">Livermore</option>
<option id="sanjose" value="sanjose">San Jose</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="go"/>
</form>
```

The JS:

```
> $(function() {
>   $("#locations").submit(function() {
>       if ($("#novato").attr("selected")) {
>           $("#pricing_novato").fadeIn("normal");
>           $("#page").fadeTo("normal", 0.1);
>           $("#pricing_novato").css({top:"0",left:"50%",margin:"20px
> 0 0 -"+($("#pricing_novato").width() /
> 2)+"px"});
>           $("#pricing_selector").fadeOut("normal");       
           }else if($("#sanleandro").attr("selected")) {
>           $("#pricing_sanleandro").fadeIn("normal");
>           $("#page").fadeTo("normal", 0.1);
>           $("#pricing_sanleandro").css({top:"0",left:"50%",margin:"20px
> 0 0
> -"+($("#pricing_sanleandro").width() / 2)+"px"});
>           $("#pricing_selector").fadeOut("normal");       
           }else if($("#livermore").attr("selected")) {
>           $("#pricing_livermore").fadeIn("normal");           $("#page").fadeTo("normal", 0.1);
>           $("#pricing_livermore").css({top:"0",left:"50%",margin:"20px
> 0 0
> -"+($("#pricing_livermore").width() / 2)+"px"});
>           $("#pricing_selector").fadeOut("normal");       
           }else if($("#sanjose").attr("selected")) {
>           $("#pricing_sanjose").fadeIn("normal");
>           $("#page").fadeTo("normal", 0.1);
>           $("#pricing_sanjose").css({top:"0",left:"50%",margin:"20px
> 0 0 -"+($("#pricing_sanjose").width()
> / 2)+"px"});
>           $("#pricing_selector").fadeOut("normal");       
           } 
  }); 
});
```

The divs:

```
<div id="pricing_novato">content</div>
<div id="pricing_sanleandro">content</div>
<div id="pricing_livermore">content</div>
<div id="pricing_sanjose">content</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a jsfiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Efb32/6/.

I changed a few things, take a look at the code: added some styles, changed the `css(...)` changes so it fits, added `return false` to the form submit code so it works in jsfiddle and added the `#page` and `#pricing_selector` divs that are used in the code. It seems to behave the same for all 4 options.

I guess I given the output I don't see what is the problem - can you check if the code on jsfiddle behaves logically as you expect or not?

Comment: wow! That's strange. I see what you did, and still can't tell why mine breaks. Here's the live link: http://76.103.255.69/earthcare/Products_residential/index2.aspx

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with styling. Try using the same `css(...)` line and add `position: relative` style - experiment with that to see if that is the problem.

Comment: I must have had some issue either in the stylesheet or in my include file, but your solution worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning the currently selected option to a variable and then test for that instead?

```
var selectedLocation = $("select option:selected").val();
```

Also, if #page is your container, won't doing this:

```
$("#page").fadeTo("normal", 0.1);
```

Fade out everything contained within the container? I only assumed because I can't see it in your code.

You could also try putting some console logging or simply alert the values you are trying to test to give you an idea of what's happening in your code

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! I added alerts to the transitions to confirm that my selections were correct, and that part worked. (Good idea!) The pricing divs are actually in an include file and are set outside the page div (but inside the body), so that part is working, too.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the var selectedLocation = $("select option:selected").val(); part. Would my test look like this?: if ($("#novato") = "selectedLocation")

Comment: that's OK :) your test would look like: if (selectedLocation = "novato") and so on... Looks like you got it fixed already though!